# Calculate combinations in MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, combinations, mips

I am working on a program that calculates combinations in MIPS. The user enters the size of the pool, and number of balls to pick from it, and the program should output the total combinations. The program correctly calculates the numerator, but when it comes to dividing the numerator (n!) by the denominator, which is also correctly calculated, the combinations number is wrong.

I think something goes wrong with $t2 when it is used in main, but not sure what exactly or how to fix it.

```
.data 

message1: .asciiz "Enter input for the size of the large pool: "
message2: .asciiz "Enter input for # of balls to be selected from large pool: "
message5: .asciiz "The numerator is: " 
 
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text 
.globl main 

main: 
    # Call on function messages 
    jal messages 
    
    
    # Calculate factrl for # from large pool size 
    move $a0, $s2
    jal factrl  # Call on factrl function 
    move $t5, $v0 
    
    # Find (n-k) for large pool 
    sub $t0, $s1, $s2
    
    # Intialize $t2 to 1 
    li $t2, 1
    
    # Call function while for large pool 
    move $a1, $s1
    move $a2, $t0
    jal while 
    move $v0, $t2
    
    # Find probability for large 
    move $a0, $v0 
    move $a1, $t0
    jal combination 
    move $t7 $v0 
    
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, newline
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 1
    add $t7, $t7, $zero 
    syscall 
    
    # Exit Program
    li $v0, 10 
    syscall 
    
messages: 

    # Request size of large pool 
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, message1 
    syscall 
    # Get input for size of large pool 
    li $v0, 5 
    syscall 
    # Store input in register
    move $s1, $v0 

    # Request # selected from large pool 
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, message2 
    syscall 
    # Get input for # of large pool 
    li $v0, 5 
    syscall 
    # Store input in register
    move $s2, $v0 
    
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, newline
    syscall 
    
    jr $ra 


factrl:     

    sw $ra, 4($sp) # save the return address 
    sw $a0, 0($sp) # save the current value of n 
    addi $sp, $sp, -8 # move stack pointer 

    slti $t0, $a0, 2 # save 1 iteration, n=0 or n =1; n!=1 
    beq $t0, $zero, L1 # not less than 2 , calculate n(n - 1)! 
    addi $v0, $zero, 1 # n=1; n!=1 
    jr $ra # now multiply 

L1: 

    addi $a0, $a0, -1 # n = n - 1 
    jal factrl # now (n - 1)! 
    addi $sp, $sp, 8 # reset the stack pointer 
    lw $a0, 0($sp) # fetch saved (n - 1) 
    lw $ra, 4($sp) # fetch return address 
    mul $v0, $a0, $v0 # multiply (n)*(n - 1) 
    jr $ra # return value n!



while: 
    
    addi $sp, $sp, -8 # allocate space in stack
    sw $ra, 4($sp)
    sw $a1, 0($sp) # store the value of $s1 on the stack 
    
    beq $a1, $a2, numerator  
    mult $t2, $a1  # multiply val x n 
    mflo $t3 
    move $t2, $t3  
    addi $a1, $a1, -1 # n = n-1 
    j while 
    
    
numerator: 
    
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, message5 
    syscall
    
    # Print the numerator 
    li $v0, 1 
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall
    
    lw $a1, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8 # reset stack pointer 
    
    jr $ra 
    

combination: 
    div $v0, $a1, $a0 
    jr $ra  

exit: 
    li $v0, 10 
    syscall
```

Comment: This is a great time to really sharpen your debugging skills.  For example, what is it you don't like about $t2?

Comment: I think somehow value of $t2 is changed after the numerator function is called, and $t2 no longer contains the needed numerator. But not sure how to fix it. It keeps giving me 268501318 as the output

Comment: These things generally don't happen randomly, so narrow it down to the instruction that causes the problem.

Comment: The `$f` registers should be used when you want float results also use the appropriate instructions for float, these with `.s` or `.d`